# Probability for Magic the Gathering

Tags: probability

So I have been trying to come up with a way to solve this math conundrum all day and haven't yet found a solution.  Here is the scenario:

I have my deck of $60$ cards.  At the start of the game I draw $7$.  Every turn (except for the first) I draw a card.  By the time I hit my fourth turn I need to have drawn $4$ cards of a set of $25$ in the deck, $1$ of a set of $4$, and $1$ (or more) of a set of $18$.

I have initially tried using choose math, and have laid out the formula as follows:

$$\dfrac{{4\choose1}{18\choose1}{25\choose4}{13\choose4}}{{60\choose10}}$$

Each of these piles are distinct sets.  Think of it like this:

\begin{align}
&\text{Item }1\text{ is a set of }&25\times \text{A}\heartsuit\\
&\text{Item }2\text{ is a set of }&4\times \text{A}\spadesuit\\
&\text{Item }3\text{ is a set of }&18\times \text{A}\diamondsuit
\end{align}

I need to get $4\times \text{A}\heartsuit$, $1\times \text{A}\spadesuit$, and $1$ or more $\text{A}\diamondsuit$. The other $13$ cards are what is left of the deck, but it doesn't matter if I draw them or not.

I am not sure if this formula I am using if correct or not, would anyone be able to tell me?

Comment: See this page for most formatting stuff http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: So the set of 25, the set of 4 and the set of 18 have no overlaps? Leaving 13 cards which are effectively useless? And you are looking at the moment when you have accumulated 10 random cards from the deck?

Comment: None of the cards in the set of 25, 4, and 18 are similar.  A think of it as a pile of 25 Ace of Diamonds, 4 Ace of Spades, and 18 Ace of Hearts.  The other 13 are part of the 60 total that make up the deck, but it doesn't matter if they are drawn or not.

Comment: I wish I still played MTG.

Comment: You are trying to count "good" hands of ten cards. You say $4$ times AH, $1$ times AS, and $n$ times AD ($n \ge 1$) is a good hand. Is $5$ times AH, $1$ times AS, and $1$ times AD _not_ a good hand? That is, is it possible to draw "too many" cards from the set of four or the set of $25$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of drawing 4 aces of hearts, 1 ace of spades, and $x$ aces of diamonds from your special deck is
$$\frac{\binom{25}{4} \binom{4}{1} \binom{18}{x} \binom{13}{5-x}}{\binom{60}{10}}$$
for $1 \le x \le 5$.  So the answer to your question is
$$\sum_{x=1}^5 \frac{\binom{25}{4} \binom{4}{1} \binom{18}{x} \binom{13}{5-x}}{\binom{60}{10}}$$

Comment: This answer assumes you must have _exactly_ 4 aces of hearts and 1 ace of spades.  If you are allowed to have more, then it gets more complicated.